# how to use not query in index field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the mapping.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/products/' -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 6, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 1 
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "product" : {
          "_all":{ "enabled": true  },
          "properties":{
            "id" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "include_in_all": true },
            "description" : { "type" : "string" },
            "title" : { "type" : "string", "boost" : 2 },
      }
        }
    }
}'
```

I don't want to get the ads which have no description. but as you can see in mapping "description" have an index.
So how do I use not query in description?
please help me out.

I seen the doc of elasticsearch and I use this query.

```
**query => {
    filtered => {
        filter => {
            not => {
                filter => {
                    term  => {description  => ''}
                }
            }
        },
        query => {
            match => { _all => $q }
        }
    }
}**
```

But it's not working, I think because description have index right?

Comment: ES version: 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2.4 this would be the correct syntax and query approach:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match_all": {}}
      ],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "description"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "description": "*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of `filtered` you have a `bool` with `must` as query and `filter as filter. What's inside of`must`is what you have as query and what's inside of`filter`is what you have as filter. The approach you used with`filtered` is deprecated in ES 2.x.